# What is wrong with this awaitReaction?

Tags: discord.js

I was just creating a command, but then I got this error:

> (node:16632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

Here is my code:

```
       .then(function (message) {
            try {
                message.react("")
                message.react("")
                message.react("")
                message.react("⬛")
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.');
            }
        })
            .then(async m => {
                await message.react('' || '' || '' || '⬛')
                var filter = (u, r) => {
                    u.id == msg.author.id && r.emoji.name == '' || r.emoji.name == '' || r.emoji.name == '' || r.emoji.name == '⬛'
                }
                message.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 30000 })
                    .then(collected => {
```

Comment: Can you add more of your code? The error is saying that `m` isn't defined.

Comment: Sure, what do you want me to add?

Comment: Few lines before that lines you sent

Comment: i edited it, and now the error is gone but now im getting a new error